# Altering Android offline battery charging display (playlpm)

Tags: android

I'm using a `ViewSonic Viewpad 7` Android tablet for an application where I'd like the tablet to power on whenever it has been turned off and power is then provided. A bit of Googling revealed that I could alter the executable /system/bin/playlpm (apparently the program responsible for showing the battery charging display when the device is off, but plugged in) to contain a simple shell script like so:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
/system/bin/reboot
```

In any event, the playlpm executable seems only to be present on Samsung devices, and not on anything else. Does anyone know that the more widely-used executable or other means used to display the battery indicator would be (and how it could be modified)?

Comment: I am not familiar with your device, does it have a battery indicator that is shown when the device is powered off but plugged in?

Comment: Yes, as far as I know, all Android devices have that, but the use of the playlpm executable seems limited to Samsung as far as I can find.