# Locating file responsible for display battery animation when charger is plugged in

Tags: android

I am trying to enable my generic android device to turn on when plugging in the charge cable. I have read that this is possible by changing the contents of playlpm to be a shell script with the reboot command inside. However, this device doesn't have this playlpm file.

A similar question was asked a while ago...
[Altering Android offline battery charging display (playlpm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7492637/altering-android-offline-battery-charging-display-playlpm), [How to make Android device boot when power is plugged in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169387/how-to-make-android-device-boot-when-power-is-plugged-in/15033519#15033519)

I assume this is specific to a certain vendor, Samsung it seems? Not sure. When I plug in a usb cable, there is a battery animation but I have no idea what gets called to show the animation. I have only found the images related to the animation. Anyways, I was wondering if someone knew what file is actually used to start this animation.